# How to prove the following propositional logic equivalence?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

The question asked me to prove the following equivalence.
$$（r \rightarrow p)\rightarrow (p\land q)\equiv (\lnot r \rightarrow p)\land(\lnot r \rightarrow q)\land (p \rightarrow q)$$

And I did the followings:

For L.H.S., 
$（r\rightarrow p)\rightarrow (p\land q)\\\equiv \lnot (\lnot r\lor p)\lor (p\land q)\\ \equiv (r \land \lnot p) \lor (p \land q)$

For R.H.S., $(\lnot r \rightarrow p)\land(\lnot r \rightarrow q)\land (p \rightarrow q)\\ \equiv (r\lor p) \land (r \lor q) \land (\lnot p \lor q)\\ \equiv (r\lor (p\land q))\land (\lnot p\lor q)\\ $

Now, I'm a bit stuck as to how to show that LHS = RHS.

Comment: This is not a do my homework for me site.  Please add your own workings into the post.  It's okay if you get stuck midway through, but you do need to show us that you're willing to meat us half-way.

Comment: Lol actually I've been working on it and I think I did it in a wrong way so I decided not to post that up here

Comment: The left hand side is equivalent to $\lnot (\lnot r\lor p)\lor (p\land q)$.  Why?  Then this is equivalent to $(r \land \lnot p) \lor (p \land q).$  Why. Show me some of your work on the right-hand side?

Comment: Cluyeia It will help us understand the mistakes you may have made, so we can better help you.  So please include your workings, right or wrong.  And how do you know they are wrong?

Comment: The R.H.S is equivalent to $(r\lor p)\land (r\lor q)\land (\lnot p\lor q)$ and it’s equivalent to $(r\lor (p\land q))\land (\not p\lor q)$ right?

Comment: Yes.  That's correct.  Now, how about you edit your post to show the work I started on the LHS, and include a copy&paste of the work you show in your comment.  That's a great start!!

Comment: I'm typing that, I'm still not getting familiar with typing latex, sorry :(

Comment: I've added that for you to your post.

Comment: What is the actual problem statement?  Are you being asked to indicate whether the proposed equivalence is true, or false?

Comment: That is the actual statement, it’s from my midterm paper and I’m reviewing it and still cannot prove it so I post it up here lol

Comment: Does my edit of your question represent your thoughts at this point?

Comment: Yea man that’s what i wrote in my paper

Comment: And I’m trying to use those distributive laws to expand it and try to simplfy it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’ve done the proof and here is the answer.

L.H.S. =
$
（r\rightarrow p)\rightarrow (p\land q)\\
\equiv \lnot (\lnot r\lor p)\lor (p\land q)\\
\equiv (r \land \lnot p) \lor (p \land q)\\
\equiv (r\lor p)\land (\lnot p \lor p)\land (r\lor q)\land (\lnot p \lor q)\\
\equiv(r\lor p)\land T\land (r\lor q)\land(\lnot p\lor q)\\
\equiv(\lnot r\rightarrow p)\land (\lnot r\rightarrow q)\land (p\rightarrow q)\\
\equiv R.H.S.
$

Thx for all your helps !

Comment: Excellent, Cluyeia!  Your answer is correct!.  Now, please feel free to accept your answer as direct and correct!  (Just click on the grey arrow to the left of your answer.  When you click on it, it will turn green.)  Don't be bashful; If I had asked the question, I would accept your answer!

Answer (score 0):

After writing out the left hand side using $\;\phi \rightarrow \psi \;\equiv\; \lnot \phi \lor \psi\;$ and DeMorgan, it is an $\;\lor\;$ of $\;\land\;$'s.  Similarly, the right hand side becomes a $\;\land\;$ of $\;\lor\;$'s.

How do you get from one to the other?  Through *distribution*.

So you choose one of the two sides, and distribute $\;\land\;$ over $\;\lor\;$, or $\;\lor\;$ over $\;\land\;$, and work towards the other side.

---

After you completed the proof, look up *conjunctive normal form* and *disjunctive normal form* and see how those terms relate to your proof.

Comment: Thanks I’ve done it ;-]